# Why is this code not working with separate javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to turn a span of text red when I click on a button. Why does the first set of code, with separate Javascript and HTML, not work... but the second set of code does?

FIRST SET (not working)

```
JAVASCRIPT:
    function focus()
    {
        getElementById('redder').style.color = '#ff0000';
    }

HTML:
    <button id="button1" onClick="javascript:focus()">cool</button>
    <span id="redder"> RED </span>
```

.
.
.

SECOND SET (working)

```
HTML:
    <button id="button1" onClick="getElementById('redder').style.color = '#ff0000';">cool</button>
    <span id="redder"> RED </span>
```

Comment: `focus()` is a native DOM function, you need to use some other name for your function.

Comment: and no need for the `javascript:` label

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. change the name of  click event handler from **focus** to something else;
2. you need use `document.getElementById()`

```
<script>
     function changeColor()
        {
            document.getElementById('redder').style.color = '#ff0000';
        }
    </script>
    <body>
        <button id="button1" onClick="changeColor();">cool</button>
        <span id="redder"> RED </span>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

When using non-inline JavaScript, you need to add the document scope:

```
document.getElementById('redder').style.color('#ff0000');
```

I think JavaScript does not need that scope when defined inline, but I can't find documentation on that quickly.

Comment: It is always safe to use `document.` and it will break in some browsers if not present, so just always use it.

Comment: Certainly JS does need the scope, there's no `window.getElementById()` method.